# using group by and aggregate function

Tags: sql

I'm not new to SQL, but I feel like I never fully understand SQL because of missing some knowledge. We all know we need to use aggregate functions when use group by, for example, we have an orderdetails table (with combination keys of orderid and productid),  to write an query that returns orders with total value (quantity * unitprice) greater than 10,000, the sql is:

```
select orderid, sum(qty*unitprice) AS totalvalue from Sales.OrderDetails
group by orderid
having sum(qty*unitprice) > 10000
```

as we know select happen after group by and having, so when I come to

```
group by orderid
having sum(qty*unitprice) > 10000
```

we have already group all the record by orderid and sum all cost, if we could image as:

```
orderid  null(a column with no name but contains the total value)

123456   11000.00
987654   12184.00
```

then it comes to select clause:

```
select orderid, sum(qty*unitprice) AS totalvalue
```

as we already have the result after the 'having' clause,
so why we need to do 'sum(qty*unitprice)' to do the sum again, isn't that redundant?

Another thing bothers me a lot is: when writing SQL, select clause comes before from clause, which is very inconvenient because you want to get IntelliSense of column names. Certainly I can write from caluse first, then "insert" the select clause, but it makes everything in a logically backward way. Am I the only person who have problem with it? ...bizzare  :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is certainly repetitive and therefore undesirable, but it's hard to avoid the repetition. You could use nested queries:

```
SELECT orderid, totalvalue
  FROM (SELECT orderid, SUM(qty * unitprice) AS totalvalue
          FROM sales.orderdetails
         GROUP BY orderid) AS order_value
 WHERE totalvalue > 10000
```

You'd need to look at your DBMS's optimizer plan to determine whether there's a significant performance penalty for doing it like that, but it avoids repeating the `SUM(qty * price)` expression. Ideally, the optimizer will push the outer WHERE clause into the inner query as a HAVING clause, but I'd not want to guarantee that it does (and different systems may, probably will, handle it differently).

Comment: I know nested query works, but just don't get the idea for the former method. Another thing bothers me is when writing SQL,   select clause comes before from clause, which is very inconvenient because you want to get IntelliSense of column names, it's no doubt that I I can write from caluse first, then "insert" the select clause, which makes your logic backward ...bizzare  :(

Answer (score 1):

First, some databases allow aliases in the `HAVING`, so you can often write:

```
select orderid, sum(qty*unitprice) AS totalvalue
from Sales.OrderDetails
group by orderid
having totalvalue > 10000;
```

Second, SQL is a *declarative* language, not a *procedural* language.  That is, what gets executed does not look anything like the statement.  In fact, it is something called a *directed acyclic graph* (in almost all databases), which has no operators that you would recognize from the SQL keywords.

This means that two identical expressions might only get calculated only once, even if they appear multiple times in the query.  Or in some cases, an expression may not be evaluated at all (such as the `select` expressions in `exists`/`not exists` subqueries).

Third, the actual `sum()` calculation (in this case) is very small compared to the actual work done by the query.  In particular, the performance issue is arranging the data for the aggregation, rather than actually processing the aggregation functions.